# Using an alias in a where clause in MySql

Tags: mysql

I've this table structure:

| HDN_Client | HDN_Type | HDN_EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client #1 | Hosting | 2022-02-01 |
| Client #2 | Hosting | 2022-03-01 |
| Client #3 | Hosting | 2022-07-30 |

I want to display the list of datas when the `HDN_EndDate` has 60 or less days between the today date and the `HDN_EndDate` date.

My query is the following one:

```
SELECT *, 
DATEDIFF(HDN_EndDate, '2022-01-17') 
    AS HDN_DateDiff 
FROM ___table 
WHERE HDN_Type='Hosting' 
   AND HDN_DateDiff<60 
ORDER BY HDN_DateDiff ASC
```

But it says that the `HDN_DateDiff` can't be used in the WHERE clause.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't refer to an alias in a `WHERE` clause defined in the same `SELECT`.  MySQL overloads its `HAVING` clause to allow it to use aliases.  The following version should work:

```sql
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(HDN_EndDate, '2022-01-17') AS HDN_DateDiff
FROM ___table
WHERE HDN_Type = 'Hosting'
HAVING HDN_DateDiff < 60
ORDER BY HDN_DateDiff;
```